# Viewpager getCurrentItem is showing wrong position

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

My Viewpager isn't working properly. I'll select an item from a list at like position 7 but then in my pager class it sets it to 0. How can I pass the position over from one page to the next?

Code for choosing item:

```
private void showItemSelectedAtPosition(int position) {
    Threads selectedThread = mData.getItem(position);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivePostPagerActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Threads", Parcels.wrap(selectedThread.getThreadItem()));
    intent.putExtra("ActiveTitle", "Active");

    startActivity(intent);

}
```

and here's the page loading in the ActivePostPagerActivity:

```
public class ActivePostPagerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ThreadResponse mData;
private ThreadFeedDataFactory mDataFactory;

private ThreadItem mThreads;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private List<ThreadItem> mThreadItems;
private PostFragment mFragment;
private String mActiveString;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_pager);

    //Load Parcel
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    mThreads = Parcels.unwrap(intent.getParcelableExtra("Threads"));

    if (getIntent().getStringExtra("ActiveTitle") != null
            && getIntent().getStringExtra("ActiveTitle").equalsIgnoreCase("Active")) {
        mActiveString = getIntent().getStringExtra("ActiveTitle");
    } else if (getIntent().getStringExtra("ActiveTitle") != null
            && getIntent().getStringExtra("ActiveTitle").equalsIgnoreCase("Watching")) {
        mActiveString = getIntent().getStringExtra("ActiveTitle");
    } else if (getIntent().getStringExtra("ActiveTitle") != null
            && getIntent().getStringExtra("ActiveTitle").equalsIgnoreCase("I'm On")) {
        mActiveString = getIntent().getStringExtra("ActiveTitle");
    }


    initUI();

}

private void initUI() {
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.postPager);
    mThreadItems = new ArrayList<>();
    mDataFactory = new ThreadFeedDataFactory(this.getApplicationContext());

    //Toolbar
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarForPosts);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_back);
    toolbar.setTitle(mActiveString);
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.mnBlue));
    toolbar.invalidate();

    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    loadData();

}

private void loadData() {

    if (getIntent().getStringExtra("ActiveTitle") != null
            && getIntent().getStringExtra("ActiveTitle").equalsIgnoreCase("Active")) {

        mDataFactory.getActiveThreadFeed(new ThreadFeedDataFactory.ThreadFeedDataFactoryCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onThreadDataReceived(ThreadResponse response) {
                mData = response;

                for (int i = 0; i <= mData.getItems().size(); i++) {
                    if (mData != null
                            && mData.getItem(i) != null
                            && mData.getItem(i).getThreadItem() != null)
                        mThreadItems.add(mData.getItem(i).getThreadItem());
                }

                populateUIWithData();

            }

            @Override
            public void onThreadDataFailed(Exception exception) {

            }
        });
    } else if (getIntent().getStringExtra("ActiveTitle") != null
            && getIntent().getStringExtra("ActiveTitle").equalsIgnoreCase("Watching")) {

        WatchedThreadsRequestData watchedThreadsRequestData = new WatchedThreadsRequestData(this);
        watchedThreadsRequestData.getWatchedData(new WatchedThreadsRequestData.WatchedThreadsFeedback() {
            @Override
            public void onWatchedRequestReceived(ThreadResponse response) {
                mData = response;

                for (int i = 0; i <= mData.getItems().size(); i++) {
                    if (mData != null
                            && mData.getItem(i) != null
                            && mData.getItem(i).getThreadItem() != null)
                        mThreadItems.add(mData.getItem(i).getThreadItem());
                }

                populateUIWithData();
            }

            @Override
            public void onWatchedRequestFailed(Exception exception) {

            }
        });

    } else if (getIntent().getStringExtra("ActiveTitle") != null
            && getIntent().getStringExtra("ActiveTitle").equalsIgnoreCase("I'm On")) {

        ThreadsImOnRequestData threadsImOnRequestData = new ThreadsImOnRequestData(this);
        threadsImOnRequestData.getThreadsImOnData(new ThreadsImOnRequestData.ThreadsImOnFeedback() {
            @Override
            public void onThreadsImOnRequestReceived(ThreadResponse response) {
                mData = response;

                for (int i = 0; i <= mData.getItems().size(); i++) {
                    if (mData != null
                            && mData.getItem(i) != null
                            && mData.getItem(i).getThreadItem() != null)
                        mThreadItems.add(mData.getItem(i).getThreadItem());
                }

                populateUIWithData();
            }

            @Override
            public void onThreadsImOnRequestFailed(Exception exception) {

            }
        });


    }


}

private void populateUIWithData() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            if (mThreadItems != null){
               ThreadItem threadItem = mThreadItems.get(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
                mFragment = PostFragment.newInstance(threadItem.getId(), threadItem.getTopic_name(),
                        threadItem.getName(), threadItem.getNum_posts());
            }
            return mFragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mThreadItems.size();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Probably a lot, please don't kill me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @sush of which class?

Comment: ActivePostPagerActivity  needed

Comment: @sush done, thank you for taking a look :)